# How can I create polygon estimates of each body part/limb that is present in an image which always contains one person?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, image-segmentation

### Background

I am working to identify and isolate each human limb of a known person, in pose, in an image which is relatively noisy.  It should also be noted that the image is a snapshot extracted from a video (which can be utilized in this task).
The end result ideally would be a bunch of polygon estimates of each body limb segment (i.e. torso, head, neck, upper arm, lower arm, hand, upper leg (thigh), lower leg, and feet/shoe).  I currently have results that allow me to find the contours of the image, though these include materials that are prevalent in the background (i.e. its not a clean image of only a human).

### Note(s)

1). I am currently using opencv to implement the task, so any answers that can be directed towards that API are greatly appreciated, though I will happily accept any general solutions that answer the question.
2). If you feel the question is lacking in clarity, please comment as to why.  I truly feel this question would add value to the community if answered completely.

### Question:

How can I create polygon estimates of each body part/limb that is present in an image which always contains one person?

Comment: The current state of the art in finding body parts is http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=145347, but starts with depth images.  The paper has a good related work section though, which will give you a good reading list to start.

Comment: Are the parts labelled ? If so this becomes a polygon fitting problem on binary shapes.